# A homomorphism from a finite dimensional vector space into itself has a non-trivial nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, abstract-algebra

I've been asked to prove the following claim:

> If V is finite dimensional and $f$ is a homomorphism of V into itself, there is some $v\neq0$ such that $f(v)=0$.

However, this does not seem true to me.

Counterexample:

Let $dim(V)=n$ for some finite number $n$. Since $n=n$ we know that $V$ is isomorphic to $V$, so we let $\phi$ be an isomorphism $\phi : V \rightarrow V$. Obviously, $\phi$ is also a homomorphism. Since $\phi$ is injective, we know that $nullity(\phi)=0$ hence for any $v \in \textbf{N}(\phi)$ it must be that $v = 0$.

Is there something that I've missed or have misconceptions about?

Comment: Right, the identity is always an injective homomorphism $V\to V$. I suspect that at some point the condition that $f$ be non-surjective got lost.

Comment: Perhaps your text uses the word "into" to mean "non-surjective", although this would be very non-standard.